# Is this a good isNaN method?

Tags: java, parsing, fixed-point

```
public boolean isNaN(String string){

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
BigDecimal bg = null;

try{

    bg = new BigDecimal(string);

}catch(Exception e){

    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

There is no native `isNaN` method for `BigDecimal`.  The thing I don't like about this method is the suppressed warning. I never use the variable but only the constructor to see if it doesn't throw an exception.  If it does, I return the corresponding `boolean`.

What do you think?

Comment: You're using exceptions to control application flow. This may not be avoidable but its not ideal. Does `BigDecimal` or any other parsing class offer a mechanism that doesn't throw exceptions? Perhaps use Apache NumberUtils `isNumber`: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber(java.lang.String) . If you must use your own implementation peek at the source for `isNumber`.

Comment: I personally would rather test for positive vs negative. IsANumber vs IsNotANumber.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan Although I agree that the resulting double negatives (like `!isNaN()`) are annoying and require you to think for a second, `isNaN` is "standard" in several programming languages.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To complement the other answer:

- I wouldn't call it `isNaN` as it's by far not obvious, that you mean "BigDecimal-NaN".
- Actually, "isNaN" is confusing, even when we know, it deals with `BigDecimal`. `NaN` is a special `double` value, which you will NOT get when you try `Double.parse("foobar")`. Moreover, there's no `Double#isNan(String)`. So I'd call it "isValidBigDecimal".
- Speed could be a concern, when you plan to use it like

  ```
    if (isNan(s)) bd = new BigDecimal(s);
  ```

  as you parse it twice. What about `tryParse` returning `null` on failure?

---

I strongly disagree with this remark:

> You should not catch Exception because it's too generic. What do you really want ?

I guess, the OP wants to know if a given string is a valid `BigDecimal`. If it's not, they'll get an `Exception` and this is a good reason to catch `Exception` here. When the code was long, then I'd also advise against catching "so much", but there is a single statement here, and the question is "does it succeed or not".

Note that, despite Javadoc, an [NPE gets also thrown](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java#BigDecimal.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29). Not catching it may be OK as `null`s are a curse and it's better to disallow them everywhere, but this decision should be done explicitly.

---

I disagree with the comment

> If one wants to handle both possibilities, one should write catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e).

The question `isNaN` should answer is "Will it return a number or throw?". This makes catching `Exception` *correct by definition*. Anything else is like a search for an alternative representation of 42. The dogma "never catch Exception" should be extended by "... unless it's exactly what you need".

So, my favorite (non-optimized) solution is

```
public BigDecimal tryParseBigDecimal(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        return new BigDecimal(string);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assert e instanceof NumberFormatException || e instanceof NullPointerException : e;
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean isValidBigDecimal(String string) {
    return tryParseBigDecimal(string) != null;
}
```

I've added an `assert` expressing out expectations. This way I'd get notified if something really strange happened.

---

A much faster solution could be to use the regex

```
[-+]?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+)(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?
```

but you can imagine that it opens quite some room for bugs.

## UPDATE

In the comments I was told that it is irresponsible to recommend (especially to newer programmers) that it is common to `catch Exception`. That's true and that's why I'm writing this. My rules are

- Be always as specific as possible. Never catch too much, especially

  - never catch a superclass when you expect a special exception
  - make you try-catch blocks as small as possible
- Always react appropriately to exceptions. Especially, never swallow them. Most of the time, declaring them in the `throws` clause is the best.

<sup>That all said, I still think that my solution is best if you need a method checking if a given String can be parsed as `BigDecimal` (and need no optimizations).</sup>

#### Update

Actually, catching `Exception` is not necessary as `RuntimeException` would do. This covers the documented `NumberFormatException`, the undocumented `NullPointerException` and all other undocumented exceptions which may get thrown. It doesn't cover checked exception, but they can't occur (unless someone uses dirty hacks), so it's fine. *I still insist that catching less is wrong.*

Comment: I would agree with you that managing 'NullPointerException' should be considered (which I did not). Your answer made me aware that there is a "special" value for NaN in Java. I think the op want a more general definition of NaN to what the abbreviation stand for, check if the input is a number or not. In fact, that was my interpretation of the question, I could be wrong.

Comment: If one wants to handle both possibilities, one should write `catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException e)`.  Even better is to simply do `if (string != null)` before trying to create a BigDecimal.  Catching all exceptions is convenient but it's almost never the right way to do things, because it obscures programmer mistakes.

Comment: @VGR I still mostly disagree, see my edit. Concerning obscuring if mistakes... yes, but I can't imagine any place leaving less place for mistakes. And guarding against mistakes in the standard library makes here no sense, as what you want to test is what the standard library does - i.e., my catch clause is tautologically correct.

Comment: Hm, coming from C#, I was going to suggest stack overflow and out of memory as two exceptions it wouldn't be appropriate to catch here. But now I realise that in Java these don't derive from Exception.

Comment: @maaartinus I think it is irresponsible to recommend (especially to newer programmers) that it is common to 'catch Exception'. This is not a best practice, it is _rarely_ appropriate and is a bad short-cut to encourage. NumberFormatException and NullPointerExeptn do the trick here just fine. If any other exceptions ever get thrown it would be prudent to evaluate the implications of them and how to handle them at that time. I believe that your assert statement is reducing readability for the same outcome, and when your assert fires we may never know what exception caused it in order to fix it!

Comment: @ultimate_guy I'll think about it. I can confirm, that the `assert` doesn't get its `cause` filled. This is a bug, IMHO. But with my current update, we know it. ### "*If any other exceptions ever get thrown it would be prudent to evaluate the implications of them and how to handle them at that time.*" - Exactly. But usually only in development, not in production. In production, you'd prefer to continue. And as I already said, with the question being "can this be parsed?", my solution is correct by definition.

Comment: @maaartinus "with the question being "can this be parsed?", my solution is correct by definition". Well note that *you* made that the definition. The question says `isNaN`. You seem to have started from the assumption that the implementation in the OP is perfect and that the requirement was wrong, whereas it seems more likely to me that it's the other way around.

Comment: @BenAaronson I'm assuming that the most useful definition of the method is the one I stated. The OP said actually about nothing and you're free to interpret their thoughts differently. So I sort of agree. I also added an update section.

Answer (score 26):

You said :

> I never use the variable but only the constructor to see if it doesn't throw an exception

I would ask you, then why did you declare a variable at all ? You could have done :

```
public boolean isNaN(final String string) {
    try {
       new BigDecimal(string);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When you don't need a variable, don't declare it.

You should not catch `Exception` because it's too generic. What do you really want ? The constructor throw `NumberFormatException` if the argument is not valid, the better option would be to catch that one instead.

Comment: Seems I got a little lightheaded there. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try to have a nicer tone, but old habits die hard. Constructor are rarely use without a variable so it's easy to have an un-used variable.

Answer (score 7):

Declaring the variable is entirely unnecessary, as has already been stated, but whether you do or not does not impact code clarity or performance, so I think it really comes down to personal preference.

The exception handling raises significantly more issues. For the most part, those have already been addressed, but I think the previous answers have skipped one major point of concern. Exceptions have their name for a reason; outside of unit tests, they should represent an *exception* to the normal flow of logic, and not play an active role in it.

The reason for this is that exceptions are really expensive, due to all the overhead in processing they imply. I would therefore replace the entire solution with RegEx that is as flexible as you need it to be and return whether or not it matches the input. For example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class NumberTester
{
        private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d*(\\.\\d+)?");

        public static boolean test(String s)
        {
                return p.matcher(s).matches();
        }
}
```

The above is a basic example, so more work will have to go into the expression if you want to match something like scientific notation, or numbers with commas, but unless your actual goal is to write *canBeParsedByBigDecimal(String s)*, I think a solution like this is significantly better.

Comment: Oops; just saw the RegEx footnote on @maaartinus's answer. I guess I'll leave this here anyway so the point is justified, since he didn't go into why the current method is slower.